# Duplicate line based on start and end date

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I could not find a way how to do the following:
My data looks as follows:

```
Time (CET)        Start              Duration(min)  End
2015-02-01 00:00  2015-02-01 00:00   2              2015-02-01 00:02
```

What I want to have is that every line (containing entries, a lot do not) gets duplicated based on the duration or end date in the following way such that:

```
Time (CET)        Start              Duration(min)  End
2015-02-01 00:00  2015-02-01 00:00   2              2015-02-01 00:02
2015-02-01 00:01  2015-02-01 00:00   2              2015-02-01 00:02
2015-02-01 00:02  2015-02-01 00:00   2              2015-02-01 00:02
```

In the end dataframe the start and end column are not necessary anymore. I thought about using shift but was not sure if it is the right away and how to use the argument freq. Any ideas how to do that?

The Time columns are in datetime format and Time (CET) is the index.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat rows by [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and add timedeltas created by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) to column `Time (CET)`:

```
print (df)
         Time (CET)             Start  Duration(min)               End
0  2015-02-01 00:00  2015-02-01 00:00              2  2015-02-01 00:02
1  2015-02-02 00:00  2015-02-02 00:00              3  2015-02-02 00:02

#convert columns to datetimes
c = ['Time (CET)','Start','End']
df[c] = df[c].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Duration(min)'] + 1)]
df['Time (CET)'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='s') * 60
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).drop(['Start','End'], axis=1)
print (df)
           Time (CET)  Duration(min)
0 2015-02-01 00:00:00              2
1 2015-02-01 00:01:00              2
2 2015-02-01 00:02:00              2
3 2015-02-02 00:00:00              3
4 2015-02-02 00:01:00              3
5 2015-02-02 00:02:00              3
6 2015-02-02 00:03:00              3
```